# Creating A blog with PHP from scratch using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Creating a blog from scratch without using any **PHP** framework, the blog will take a folder inside my domain root like this `domain.com/blog`

How could i make an htaccess file that makes my blog posts take links like this :

```
domain.com/blog/blog-post-test-link-foo-bar
```

Instead of this way :

```
domain.com/blog/post.php?id=1
```

Also, In my post.php file, i want to select the data of that post similar to the **Slug** in the url.

How could i do that in pure php way?

Comment: This might be more of a serverfault question.

Comment: @OIS This is not a server fault question. It seems this has nothing to do with .htaccess. If you are creating the blog from scratch why not just store the id in a database along with the path? Plenty of Open source projects do this, maybe use of them.

Comment: @hoss he wants to write a RewriteRule. And he wants us to write his PHP code for him.

Comment: Not even a rewriterule could handle this, it has no way of knowing what id links to foo-bar. But yes I agree. this question is a non question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the /blog/ folder and inside it you can put an .htaccess file like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . ./index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your index.php you would write something like:

```
<?php
$base = '/blog/';
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$slug = substr($uri, strlen($base));

// Identify the ID of the post
// You identify the ID by searching your posts database on a field like "slug"
// But for now we'll just load from an array
$posts = array(
    'blog-post-test-link-foo-bar' => 1
);
$postId = isset($posts[$slug]) ? $posts[$slug] : null;

if (!is_null($postId)) {
    // Load the post from the database, 
    // or use it if you already loaded it together with the ID
    echo "Loading!";
} else {
    echo "Invalid post!";
}
```